# unable to play audio in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

My homepage has a video background which has audio. But the audio will only automatically play using `firefox`. If I'm going to open my homepage in others like `chrome` or `IE`, the audio doesn't be heard.

Comment: Can you give us a link / specific code to look at?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Many browsers, including Chrome, BLOCK and do not honor the autoplay functions. They require user action to be taken to play autoplay media, such as a click handler invoking it.

Here's some additional information [HTML5 Audio: Chrome on Android doesn't automatically play song vs Chrome on PC does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587977/html5-audio-chrome-on-android-doesnt-automatically-play-song-vs-chrome-on-pc-d)

Comment: There are lots of ways around this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525968/autoplay-sound-in-chrome-background-tab)