# Recording audio on chrome for android devices Bug?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, mediarecorder-api

I'm using **Media​Stream Recording API** to record user's MIC.  The code works fine on chrome windows but when it comes to android it just stops recording instantly after recording beep.

How can I make the API work on android devices?
Am I missing something or this is a bug with Web Audio API?

Here is the code:

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
    .then(stream => {
        rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        rec.ondataavailable = e => {
            audioChunks.push(e.data);
            if (rec.state == "inactive"){
        let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
        recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Then I just use these lines to start recording :

```
audioChunks = [];
rec.start();
```

And This one to stop and play:

```
rec.stop();
recordedAudio.autoplay = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome autoplay requires user interaction to play a sound.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587977/html5-audio-chrome-on-android-doesnt-automatically-play-song-vs-chrome-on-pc-d) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206631/html5-audio-cant-play-through-javascript-unless-triggered-manually-once?rq=1) for javascript based workarounds.

Or if you are making an android app and using webview to load your page, try setting 
[setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)) to false.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Comment: Did you check the permissions? is there any error in Logcat?

Comment: Ok... It actually is a voice recognition app (recognition works fine both on Android and Desktop) that when you say "My name is Jack" it'll record and playback your voice.

Comment: It works fine on Windows chrome but when I try it on Android chrome I can hear start recording beep then, instantly recording ends... No time for recording on Android...

Comment: Okay, I was assuming you were trying to make an android app. 
So if recording works fine, are you facing problem is with playback?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194588/discussion-between-aparna-and-sara-ree).